# Rewrite in php site, slash getting omitted?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I'm new to rewrite and right now I have a genuine problem with rewrite. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
2/cat23/subcat104/Shoes (I am trying to change this url to products.php?p=2&m_id=23&s_id=104&pg=Shoes )
```

The above represents (2=page number),(23=categoryid),(104=Subcategoryid),(Shoes=subcategoryname)

Now on iterating my `$_request` I get this:

```
p => 2
m_id => 23
pg => subcat104/Shoes (it didn't separated them since the '/' was also present between them)
```

Now following is my rewrite rule which seems ok but not delivering the result.

```
*RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/cat([0-9]+)/subcat([0-9]+)/(.+)$ products.php?p=$1&m_id=$2&s_id=$3&pg=$4 [NC]*
```

and I wanted the result to be:

```
*p => 2
m_id => 23
s_id=>104
pg => Shoes*
```

Comment: Please show a `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: array(3) { ["p"]=> string(1) "2" ["m_id"]=> string(2) "23" ["pg"]=> string(12) "sc104/Bath" }

Comment: can you try to replace `[NC]` with `[L,NC]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and it works for me, I added your Rewrite code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/cat([0-9]+)/subcat([0-9]+)/(.+)$ products.php?p=$1&m_id=$2&s_id=$3&pg=$4 [NC]
```

Make sure you have declared the `RewriteEngine On` before the rule.

The result I got from `$_REQUEST` was:

```
Array
(
    [p] => 2
    [m_id] => 23
    [s_id] => 104
    [pg] => Shoes
)
```

If you are still having trouble, post your `.htaccess` file and a `var_dump`.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/cat([0-9]+)/(.+)$ products.php?p=$1&m_id=$2&pg=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/cat([0-9]+)/subcat([0-9]+)/(.+)$ products.php?p=$1&m_id=$2&s_id=$3&pg=$4 [NC]                                                                     what i did to make it work , was just to place the second statement before the first one and it worked. Sorry i didnot  tried that before  asking.                                                                           Like what was happening was second statement was overwriting the first one and hence ommiting '/'. :-)